Error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'fromBasePath') on hubot creating
I try install hubot on this guide
Guide link
For zulip chat, but when i execute yo hubot and set data bot get error:
`? My Owner myhubot
? Bot name mybot
? Description A simple helpful robot for your Company
? Bot adapter shell
                     _____________________________
                    /                             \
   //\              |      Extracting input for    |
  ////\    _____    |   self-replication process   |
 //////\  /_____\   \                             /
 ======= |[^_/\_]|   /----------------------------
  |   | _|___@@__|__
  +===+/  ///     \_\
   | |_\ /// HUBOT/\\
   |___/\//      /  \\
         \      /   +---+
          \____/    |   |
           | //|    +===+
            \//      |xx|

✖ An error occured while running hubot:app#writing
Error hubot

Cannot read properties of null (reading 'fromBasePath')
`

What wrong?
yo doctor say Everything looks all right!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The problem appears to be a bug in generator-hubot, see https://github.com/hubotio/generator-hubot/issues/115.
Not sure how best to work around this until they release a new version of the package. You could manually modify generator-hubot/generators/app/index.js on your filestystem and change the this.copyTemplate invocations to pass undefined instead of null. That is obviously super hacky, but worked for me.
